# I want to make the field to be unique but at same time can be null

Tags: python, django-models

I have a custom user model I have some fields it can be null or has value but if so this value want it unique here are my code :

```
def unique_constraint_q(*fields):
    """
    Returns a Q object that checks for uniqueness based on provided fields.
    """
    conditions = [Q(**{field: val}) for field, val in fields]
    return Q(*conditions, _connector=Q.OR)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(
        self, email=None, mobile_number=None, password=None, **extra_fields
    ):
        if not email and not mobile_number:
            raise ValueError(
                _("User must have either an email address or a mobile number")
            )

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            mobile_number=mobile_number,
            **extra_fields,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email=None, mobile_number=None, password=None):
        if not email and not mobile_number:
            raise ValueError(
                _("Superuser must have either an email address or a mobile number")
            )

        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            mobile_number="0123456789",
            password=password,
            role=User.Role.SUPERUSER,  # Set the role to SUPERUSER for superuser
            name="KhalMag",
            name_ar="كالماج",  # Set the desired name for superuser
        )

        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.photo = "default_photos/km2.jpg"

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = "ADMIN", _("Admin")
        SUPERUSER = "SUPERUSER", _("SuperUser")
        OWNER = "OWNER", _("Owner")
        ACCOUNTANT_MONTH = "ACCOUNTANT_MONTH", _("Accountant For Month")
        ACCOUNTANT_PERIOD = "ACCOUNTANT_PERIOD", _("Accountant For Period")
        HR = "HR", _("HR")
        NORMAL = "NORMAL", _("Normal")

    GENDER_CHOICES = [("male", _("Male")), ("female", _("Female"))]

    mobile_num_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex="^[0-9]{10}$", message=_("Entered mobile number isn't in a right format!")
    )
    id_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex="^[0-9]{15}$", message=_("Entered ID number isn't in a right format!")
    )
    # user personal info
    user_id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name_ar = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    passport = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        error_messages={
            "unique": _("A user with this passport number already exists."),
        },
    )
    identification = models.CharField(
        validators=[id_regex],
        max_length=15,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        error_messages={
            "unique": _("A user with this identification number already exists."),
        },
    )
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices, default=Role.NORMAL)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        default="male",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    education = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    home_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(
        validators=[mobile_num_regex],
        unique=True,
        max_length=11,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        error_messages={
            "unique": _("A user with this mobile number already exists."),
        },
    )

    photo = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to=user_photo_file_path,
    )

    # user's bank info
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bank_branch = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bank_account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bank_account_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_user_passport",
                fields=["passport"],
                condition=Q(passport__isnull=False),
            ),
            UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_user_identification",
                fields=["identification"],
                condition=Q(identification__isnull=False),
            ),
            UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_user_mobile_number",
                fields=["mobile_number"],
                condition=Q(mobile_number__isnull=False),
            ),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

```
I created one user with it with these fields are null but when I want to create another I got this:
```

## IntegrityError at /en/api/users/create_user/

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: user_user.mobile_number
```

Request Method:POSTRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/api/users/create_user/Django Version:4.1.5Exception Type:IntegrityErrorException Value:UNIQUE constraint failed: user_user.mobile_numberException Location:C:\Users\Khaleel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 357, in executeRaised during:user.views.CreateUserViewPython Executable:C:\Users\Khaleel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exePython Version:3.10.2Python Path:['E:\\gigs\\partitions-rent-api\\rent_manager_api', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Khaleel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']Server time:Wed, 08 Nov 2023 14:25:15 +0000

Comment: There is a lot of code, but you only mention one field (and you don't even mention which field is the problematic one). Can you reduce your code to just the relevant field? In other words, can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: `blank=True` might be the problem. See the suggested duplicate.